What type of outlet has four vertical slots and how can I modernize it?
I live in a 1920s house. There is this outlet in one of the rooms, off of the living room. We think it was a sunroom.
Is there anything I can do with basic electrical knowledge to convert to a regular old plug without messing around at the breaker?

Home is in USA
Outlet is live, because I tested it with non-contact voltage tester and got a reading out of two of the four slots.
Outlet reads as ~120V
Added more photos. Now including wires and j box.
*Outlet shares a breaker with a regular old 15amp outlet on the other side of the wall.
The cloth sheathing on the wires still feels good to me, it doesn't crumble, and is pliable.



[

"North America" certainly includes Canada, the USA, and Mexico, and possibly other countries. Would you care to narrow this down? If Canada, which province?

and of course.. with basic electrical knowledge I would first pull the outlet cover and check it out and then decide how to wire in a more useful modern outlet, whether at 240v or 120v.   maybe it's just me but this should go without saying,

@crip659, in 1920, North America was still converging on Hubbell's 1912 socket design as the standard, while BS-73 was only five years old.  I wouldn't assume anything about a socket from that era without either looking at the wiring or testing it with a voltmeter.

Adding my voice to those who say a complete decommissioning of all wiring from this era should be your priority. I don't like answering specific questions by expanding the scope 1,000 times. You can always say "whoa hey, rebuild it all from scratch". That's not the usual spirit of this forum but this is a rather extreme case. Really consider that option.

@jay613 Thanks for the input. I was saying down below that the house actually has decent electrical. Modern wiring mixed in with some older work. No knob and tube. Had an electrical inspection again after we moved in and they were pleased at the condition and didn't really have any worries. This specific outlet that I'm asking about is 1 of 1 in the house.

Interesting.  When you remove the junction box it would be interesting to see the cable type connected to it.

@jay613 photos added of the wiring in the j box. I should also note that there is an 15amp outlet on the opposite side of the wall that shares a breaker

Wow.  Metal clad cable so probably original 1920s BX?   There is a patch made with tape there, perhaps feeding the second outlet.  If you're going to keep using that wire be very gentle because the insulation is brittle. I suggest replacing the tape patch with Wago 221s, 3 port adding a long piece of new stranded wire as a tail then gently push it all to the back of the box and hope you never have to touch it again. All work on your new outlet will be with your tails that will not put stress on the old wires.

@jay613 Yeah, that makes sense! house is from the 20s. They rewired some of the house, but not all. It looks like to me 2 black wires come out of the top conduit and 2 white wires come out of the bottom one. Does that make any sense?
Does it seem like to you this would be fine to change to a modern outlet? Fine in terms of it's the same wiring as every other outlet in the house. I know there are inherent risks with this type of old wiring

No, should be a black and white in each cable.  Hard to see without unraveling, which you should not do unnecessarily.  Assume the obvious.  Yes new outlet, actually, install a GFCI outlet here and use its  Load terminals to feed the next outlet.  STILL use 4 2-port Wagos and long tails so you aren't manipulating the old cable into the new outlet.

You should not use this outlet or the cable feeding it without more experience and without doing some work at the breaker panel.
I am picking up on Peter Bill's comment to Mannaseh's answer, and credit to Manasseh for identifying the "parallel tandem outlet", but my answer will take a different direction.

The socket is designed to accept a polarized 120V plug on one pair of terminals and a 240V plug on the other.  It may be wired with only 120 or 240V in which case one pair of holes will be dead.     It is not a modern 4-wire combo outlet like for a dryer.  It is a prehistoric outlet designed to deliver either 120 or 240V or perhaps both but not at the same time to the same device.  There were no such devices at that time.
There is no ground here and it's very doubtful there is any ground in the box behind it.
It's about 90 years old.  It's likely the wiring is also that old because who would update the wiring and keep this thing?  If the wiring is that old it's either K&T or some early paper/cloth/tar  insulated NM.

So.  To answer the exact question you asked: No!  there is no way for you to use this outlet without messing around at the breaker.   You really should run new wiring here.   There are some sketchy ways you could use the existing wires with a new outlet, but they all require you to have knowledge and experience, to carefully inspect the condition of the wires, take measurements, and install an AFCI breaker to mitigate the risk of using century-old wire.  To answer the question you asked: Don't do it, don't use this outlet or the cable feeding it.

TLDR; there's likely a reason this kind of outlet isn't used anymore.

@JimmyJames I wouldn't put this in the answer because it's safer to inspect this thing under a microscope but if the outlet is wired for 120V, and powered up, it should work for any two-prong device.  The 120V configuration is the same as today's.  Interesting beginner reading on Harvey Hubbell.

"it should work for any two-prong device" That seems scary. Maybe it would be fine, but I wouldn't use it.

Yeah and I bet the rest of the wiring in the house is knob and tube too, with nary a metal box in sight at any of the switches or outlets. Delete it all and put in new wiring everywhere!! I had a house full of knob and tube and the stopgap was to put GFCI's between the (new) panel and the knob and tube. But it wasn't sufficient, I could pick up a lot of current with a non-contact voltage detector even a foot away from the wall. There are just too many cracks in those old wires, and no grounding at all.

@sjb-sjb GF or AF ?

Hi @jay613, they were GFCI's. I do wonder whether they should have been AFCIs or actually both. But either way the fact is that wiring from the 20's and 30's is brittle and ungrounded. It should all be decommissioned ASAP !

@sjb-sjb on the contrary! The house is not knob and tube. The house does have a mishmash of new wiring and old wiring though. Some are grounded, some are not. Some are ungrounded 3 prong too! Mostly all metal boxes however. I think the people who lived here before us only ever did exactly what was needed at the time. Everything is piecemeal here. Most issues will be resolved while we upgrade to 200amp service sometime this year.

That looks like this receptacle listed on the Wikipedia receptacle history page:

Credit: By Wa2ise at English Wikipedia - Transferred from en.wikipedia to Commons by BPK., Public Domain, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=7666293
The first step is to find out if it is "live". You can use a non-contact voltage tester for that. If it is live then you can use a multimeter to check the voltage between each pair of holes. If you get (nominally) either ~ 120V or 0V for each combination then this can be replaced with a standard 5-15 receptacle, provided (a) the wires are big enough (14 AWG minimum) and there is a ground available (either a ground wire or grounded metal conduit).
If you get (nominally) ~ 240V from at least some of the combinations then you may have to make a breaker change to get this to work properly. Actually, if it is ~ 240V but includes a proper neutral and ground (which it may or may not, despite appearing to have 4 wires) then you can cap one hot and use one hot/neutral/ground for a 120V receptacle. However, if that is the case then it may be better to change the breaker anyway if your panel is full or nearly full as that would free up space for another circuit.
If you get nothing at all - not "live" - then you will have to do some more research to figure out where it is connected and why it is not currently working. No matter what you find, you will need to check the wire size to determine what size circuit you can install. Standard US circuits start at 15A (14 AWG) and go up from there (20A = 12 AWG, etc.).
Except for initially determining voltages, all work must be done with the breaker turned off and only after verifying that there is no power to any part of the receptacle.

Roger that. It's live for sure. Will test multimeter when I return home in two days.

I took the liberty of adding the Wikipedia page this picture was on, I hope that's OK.

I would be VERY wary of trusting 100-year-old cabling, especially at 240V. If the cable is the same vintage as the outlet, rewiring would be advised.

@Peterbill Agree about the general concern, particularly since older insulation often falls apart when you touch it. That being said, 240V and 120V are little different - most insulation now is rated for 600V and even 300V insulation will be fine for 240V circuits. The issue is whether the insulation is intact or not.

@Peterbill and Manasseh thanks for the shoulders to stand on.    You are both correct but I wrote an answer that's far more emphatic in its conclusion.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact add to that the the insulation on the wiring is likely to be in a state where it crumbles as soon as anything is moved. So even if there isn't a short now, the situation could be hazardous after investigation. FIND THE OTHER END OF THAT WIRING, AND ISOLATE IT.

@Peterbill if its been fine for 100 years, it will probably continue to be fine as long as it isn't disturbed.

@HurricaneHamilton There is one additional concern, which can only be resolved by checking the wires (either at the breaker or behind this receptacle) - wire size. Since this receptacle was rated for 10A, it is possible, though unlikely, that this could be smaller than 14 AWG wire and not allowable for a 15A circuit. In theory that should have been checked/handled with a previous panel upgrade, but you never know...

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact added some new photos and more clarification.
